# Increase Log size and retention period of Message Hub (Apache Kafka) on IBM Public Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, apache-kafka, message-hub

Is there a way to increase log size of Message Hub (Apache Kafka) from 1 GB (retention.bytes)  to 50 GB and log retention from 24 hours on Public Bluemix?

Comment: I thought it would be interesting  to run a poll on twitter to understand typical partition size: https://twitter.com/csnow_uk/status/898822351353151488

Answer (score 3):

There is currently not a way to increase the retention bytes, but as of last week you are able to modify the retention time. It still defaults to 24 hours, but you can now set it to be anything from 1 hour to 30 days via either the Bluemix dashboard or the administration interface.